# Change text-color of radio button Angular 11

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, forms

so I have these radio buttons:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" class="location_filter">
        <label style="font-weight: 500; color: #C0C0C0">Select a button: </label>
        <mat-radio-group>
            <div class="p-field-radiobutton">
                <mat-radio-button name="locationType" (click)="clickeEvent()" value="theFirst"
                 [disabled]="isDisabled" inputId="theFirst" formControlName="locationType" id="myRadioButton" >
                </mat-radio-button>
                <label for="theFirst" id="1Radio">Radio 1</label>
            </div>


            <div class="p-field-radiobutton">
                <mat-radio-button name="locationType" (click)="clickeEvent()" value="theSecond"
                    [disabled]="isDisabled" inputId="theSecond" formControlName="locationType" >
                </mat-radio-button>
                <label for="theSecond" style="color: #C0C0C0">Radio 2</label>
            </div>

        </mat-radio-group>
    </form>
```

I have 3 questions:

1. How do I default to the first radio on page load?
2. How do I change text color when the particular radio button is selected?
3. I have the buttons disables depending on a condition, how do I also disable the clickevent attached to it?

I'm a little weak angular forms, so any help or suggestions are much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### How do I default to the first radio on page load?

For this, you can use the checked property and assign either true/false based on which one you want to select/unselect by default like this -

```
<mat-radio-button [checked]="true">Radio button 1</mat-radio-button>
<mat-radio-button [checked]="false">Radio button 2</mat-radio-button>
```

### How do I change text color when the particular radio button is selected?

There are multiple ways to do that like ngStyle & ngClass. You can read about them [here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/).

### I have the buttons disables depending on a condition, how do I also disable the clickevent attached to it?

You can use the following CSS property to make the radio button not clickable. Also you can add this property using ngStyle/ngClass when radio button is disabled.

```
pointer-events: none
```

Comment: I get this error:
Property 'checked' does not exist on type "nameofcomponent'. Do I have to declare something in TS?

Comment: No you don't have to define anything in TS file for [checked] property. Find a working example here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/radio-button-checked?file=app/app.component.ts